# Taking a string of period separated properties and converting it to a json object in php

Tags: php, string, arraylist

I'm fairly sure I'm missing something blindingly obvious here but here it goes.

I am working on updating a search function in an application which was running a loop and doing a very large number of sql queries to get object / table relations to one large query that returns everything. However the only way I could think to return relations was period separated, what I am now wanting to do is take the flat array of keys and values and convert it into an associative array to then be jsonified with json_encode.

For example what I have is this...

```
array(
     "ID"=>10,
     "CompanyName"=>"Some Company",
     "CompanyStatusID"=>2,
     "CompanyStatus.Status"=>"Active",
     "addressID"=>134,
     "address.postcode"=>"XXX XXXX",
     "address.street"=>"Some Street"
);
```

And what I want to turn it into is this...

```
array(
     "ID"=>10,
     "CompanyName"=>"Some Company",
     "CompanyStatusID"=>2,
     "CompanyStatus"=>array(
          "Status"=>"Active"
     ),
     "addressID"=>134,
     "address"=>array(
          "postcode"=>"XXX XXXX",
          "street"=>"Some Street"
     )
);
```

Now I'm sure this should be a fairly simple recursive loop but for the life of me this morning I can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Graham.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function was part way there mike, though it had the problem that the top level value kept getting reset on each pass of the array so only the last period separated property made it in.

Please see updated version.

```
function parse_array($src) {
    $dst = array();
    foreach($src as $key => $val) {
        $parts = explode(".", $key);
        if(count($parts) > 1) {
            $index = &$dst;
            $i = 0;
            $count = count($parts)-1;
            foreach(array_slice($parts,0) as $part) {
                if($i == $count) {
                    $index[$part] = $val;
                } else {
                    if(!isset($index[$part])){
                        $index[$part] = array();
                    }
                }
                $index = &$index[$part];
                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            $dst[$parts[0]] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $dst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is something more elegant, but quick and dirty:

```
$arr = array(
     "ID"=>10,
     "CompanyName"=>"Some Company",
     "CompanyStatusID"=>2,
     "CompanyStatus.Status"=>"Active",
     "addressID"=>134,
     "address.postcode"=>"XXX XXXX",
     "address.street"=>"Some Street"
);
$narr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    if (preg_match("~\.~", $key))
    {
        $parts = split("\.", $key);
        $narr [$parts[0]][$parts[1]] = $val;
    }
    else    $narr [$key] = $val;
}
```

Comment: That would work though I think I need something a little more dynamic, for example a relation could be upto five levels deep, I guess there could be a switch counting the parts though it's always going to require updating if the max depth changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
     "ID" => 10,
     "CompanyName" => "Some Company",
     "CompanyStatusID" => 2,
     "CompanyStatus.Status" => "Active",
     "addressID" => 134,
     "address.postcode" => "XXX XXXX",
     "address.street" => "Some Street",
     "1.2.3.4.5" => "Some nested value"
);

function parse_array ($src) {
    $dst = array();

    foreach($src as $key => $val) {

        $parts = explode(".", $key);

        $dst[$parts[0]] = $val;

        if(count($parts) > 1) {
            $index = &$dst[$parts[0]];
            foreach(array_slice($parts, 1) as $part) {
                $index = array($part => $val);
                $index = &$index[$part];
            }
        }
    }

    return $dst;
}

print_r(parse_array($arr));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 10
    [CompanyName] => Some Company
    [CompanyStatusID] => 2
    [CompanyStatus] => Array
        (
            [Status] => Active
        )

    [addressID] => 134
    [address] => Array
        (
            [street] => Some Street
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [5] => Some nested value
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: To use pointers that't the solution. Thank you very much Mike.